# How to use a button to add an item to another view on Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, ipad

I've got a basic restaurant menu system for the iPad using storyboards, and I have a product view with a button to add the item to the order page, how can I get it so that when the user presses the add to order button it adds the product name to the order scene. I've thought about using a table view in the order page but I don't know if that was a good idea. Mainly I just need some help on how to get it to print the corresponding product name onto the order page when the button is pressed. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Aislinn

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get it so that when the user presses the add to order button it adds the product name to the order scene.

You're mixing up presentation and data, which is a bad idea.  Create a representation of orders that has no view logic at all.  When a button is pressed to add something to an order, the view controller should tell the class that manages orders to do so.  When you need to display an order, the view controller should ask the class for the details.  For more information, read up on the MVC design pattern, which Apple uses heavily.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the product name to an `NSMutableArray` and have the tableview load the items from this array and display it to the user.

**Edit:**

When the user clicks the button to add the product, use `[arrayName addObject:@"Product Name"]`. Then, to load it in the tableview, use the tableview's delegate method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}` to load the name into the cell. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *identity = @"MainCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identity] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = [arrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: and how would you go about this?